# Using a thread safe static mutable Map of Map in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I need to add a static thread safe HashMap. I have something like this -

```
private static Map<String, ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ClassA>> myCache =
      new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ClassA>>();
```

Even though I am using **ConcurrentHashMap**, I see that if main thread is adding element in the myCache, and when the same is accessed in other thread even at later time, it does not have the latest data in the myCache object. For e.g

Thread 1: Adds entry to the map
`myCache = {a1={1=com.x.y.z.ClassA@3ec8b657}}`

Thread 2: Access the same key `a1`. But it does not see the data added by Thread 1. Rather it sees empty value for this key  `myCache = {a1={}}`
As a result, data is getting corrupted. Entries added for the `a1` key in Thread 1 are not visible in Thread 2.

Thanks in advance for any pointers on how can I update this map in thread safe manner.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] showing how you update and read the map currently.

Comment: The @Ryan answer is a good way to achieve what you want.  Note that you implement a class that does not, necessarily extend Map.  The new class must proxy all Map methods that you wish to use (putAll, clear, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Ryan answer is essentially correct.

Remember that you must proxy every `Map` method that you wish to use
and you must synchronize to the `cashe` element within every proxied method.

For example:

```
public void clear()
{
  synchronized(cache)
  {
    cache.clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Even though I am using ConcurrentHashMap, I see that if main thread is adding element in the myCache, and when the same is accessed in other thread even at later time, it does not have the latest data in the myCache object.

`ConcurrentHashMap` is running in a large number of applications around the world at this instance.  If your fairly typical use case didn't work appropriately, many critical systems would be failing.

Something is going on but chances are high that it is nothing to do with `ConcurrentHashMap`.  So here are some questions for you to help you debug your code:

- Are you sure that the cache lookup happens *after* the cache put?  `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't save you from race conditions in your code.
- Any chance this is a problem with the `hashcode()` or `equals()` functions of the key object?  By default the `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods are for the object *instance* and not the object value.  See the [consistency requirements](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts#:%7E:text=internal%20consistency%3A%20the%20value%20of,may%20have%20the%20same%20hashCode).
- Any chance that the cache lookup happens *after* a cache remove or a timeout of the cache value?  Is there cache cleanup logic?
- Do you have logic that does 2 operations on the `ConcurrentHashMap`.  For example testing for existence of a cache entry and then making another call to put the value?  You should be using `putIfAbsent(...)` or the other atomic calls if so.

If you edit your post and show a *small* sample of your code with the key object, the real source of the issue may be revealed.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had good results with ConcurrentHashMap.  When I need thread safety, I usally do something like this:

```
public class Cache<K, V> {
    private Map<K, V> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public V get(K key) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            return cache.get(key);
        }
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            cache.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` is fully concurrent.  You should not need to `synchronize` on it unless you are making multiple calls and can't use `putIfAbsent(...)` or other calls.

Comment: @Gray You just contradicted yourself.  If it doesn't work well with multiple calls across threads then it's not "fully concurrent."  As I said before, I've never had ConcurrentHashMap work as described in the documentation.  Easier to just handle it myself.

Comment: Sorry @Ryan but I didn't.  `ConcurrentHashMap` will never be corrupted by multiple calls.  That the guarantee of it being "fully concurrent".  I was just pointing out that if you call `concurrentMap.get()` and then `concurrentMap.put()`, the state of the map may have changed between those two calls.  That's a problem with _your_ code and not with the `ConcurrentHashMap` code.

Comment: Hi. thank you @Ryan. +1 for your help. the field "cached" must be final, isn't it?